# UITableview scrolling postion on didselectrow

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` which consist of Chapters and Subchapters. On selecting Chapters the respective Subchapter will expand in `UITableView`. When I click the last Chapter the subchapter is not visible in the screen. Have to scroll below automatically when the subchapters appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use

```
[self.table scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:NO];
```

Or use

```
CGPoint bottomOffset = CGPointMake(0, yourTableView.contentSize.height - yourTableView.frame.size.height);
[table setContentOffset:bottomOffset]
```

This will scroll the tableView to the bottom when a new cell will be inserted to your tableView

Answer (score 0):

On `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method you need something like this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
...
    [tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:indexPath.section] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
    CGRect sectionRect = [tableView rectForSection:indexPath.section];
    [tableView scrollRectToVisible:sectionRect animated:YES];
...
}
```

Hope it helps.